# É uma má prática usar foreach dentro da View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

É uma má prática usar `foreach` dentro da *View*? Se é, como fazer?

Comment: Não...
Isso é normal. Bastante comum na construção de tables.

Comment: Não depende do **foreach** e sim do **IEnumerable** que você está usando no loop. **foreach** por si só é tão válido quanto o **if**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É má prática?

Não. O *foreach* pode ser utilizado para exibir dados na View normalmente.

Exemplo: Supondo que meu model (classe do tipo ProdutosViewModel) possua uma lista de produtos e eu desejo exibir o nome e o valor de cada produto.

```
@model ProdutosViewModel
    ...
    @foreach produto in Model.Produtos
    {
        //Código para exibir dados do produto
        <tr>
         <td>@produto.Nome</td>
         <td>@produto.Valor</td>
        </tr>
    }
    ...
```

**Mas se você tem muitos registros** para iterar é interessante usar um recurso de paginação por exemplo, até mesmo para uma melhor experiência com o usuário.

Quando as pessoas dizem não colocar lógica na View, elas estão geralmente referindo-se a lógica de negócios. Uma vez que você está utilizando o *foreach* apenas para exibir uma informação na página não é uma má prática utilizá-lo na View.

Answer (score 4):

**Não!**

Má prática é realizar regras de negócio na view. Outra má prática muito comum é repetição de código, *copiar e colar* sempre o mesmo código ao invés de criar uma *partial view*.

Mas, por *foreach* apenas, é impossível dizer. A má prática pode estar no que você está fazendo no loop, mas não pelo fato de estar utilizando-o.